# How is seen the BER of a BPSK DSSS?

Tags: bpsk, spread-spectrum, performance

I am trying to understand the DSSS (spread spectrum) performance improvments.

Let's consider that we are in BPSK and on a AWGN channel without any interferences or adjacent signals.

Is the theoretical BER for a given Eb/N0 the same using or not DSSS? Does the DSSS improve the sensitivity level of a receiver?

Comment: The answer to the first question is "The same".  For the second question, you need to tell us what _you_ understand by the sensitivity level of the receiver.

Comment: If the BER starts to be null at a given dBm level without DSSS can I expect to go lower with it?

Comment: There is _no_ dBm level at which the BER is $0$.  At large SNR, the BER can be _very_ small, but it never can be $0$.  The presence or absence of DSSS makes _no_ difference to this fact.  The theoretical BER for a given $E_b/N_0$ ratio is the same whether you are using plain BPSK or BPSK with DSSS modulation.  What DSSS changes is the _bandwidth_  of the transmitted signal, and hence lowers the  _carrier_-to-noise ratio.  See also [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/2846/235).

Comment: You answered my question, thanks